# Access Identity User and Role Tables in Linq

Tags: linq

I am learning Linq and MVC. I have created MVC project in which i have used identity tables for user login. I have create Employee model in which i have used Aspnetuser id as a foreign key. I have assigned each employee a role admin, approver etc.

when I create a controller of employee it automatically creates this LINQ query

```
     var employee = db.Employee.Include(e => e.Department)
                               .Include(e => e.Designation)
                               .Include(e => e.Organization)
                               .Include(e => e.User);

        return View(employee.ToList());
```

i want to make join a of this linq to aspnetusers table than aspnetusers table to aspnetuserroles so i can get the role of the employee.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing the structure of you Employee model, but I'll take a guess, and suggest adding:

```
 .Include(e =>e.User.Roles);
```

to the end of that statement.